# Expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token

Tags: c++, vector, g++

There are two errors I get from the code. I believe they have to do with the fact that I created a vector object that holds vector objects of type `int`(ie a vector of vectors). When I tried to access the array of vectors in the vector object using the subscript operator I get an error message which is the same as the title of this post.

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> M;
    vector<vector<int>> cases;

    int numberOfCase;
    cin >> numberOfCase;
    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfCase; i++)
    {
        int s;
        cin >> s;
        for(int j = 1; j <= s; j++)
            cin >> M[j];
        cases.push_back(M);

    }
    // determine size of M;
    vector<int> seen;
    for(int i = 1; i <= cases.size(); i++)
    {

        for(int j = 1; j < cases[i].size(); j++)
        {
            for(int w = 1; w < seen.size(); w++)
            {
                if(cases[i].[j] == seen[w]);// error
                else
                    seen.push_back(cases[i].[j]); // error
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= seen.size(); i++)
        cout << seen[i] << " ";

}
```

Comment: What are the actual errors you have?

Comment: main.cpp:38:30: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
                 if((cases[i].[j]) == seen[w]);

Comment: vectors start at index 0 and end at size() - 1.

Comment: `cin >> M[j];` causes undefined behaviour as `M` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the errors you have, your problem lies in these lines of code:

```
for(int j = 1; j < cases[i].size(); j++)
{
    for(int w = 1; w <= seen.size(); w++)
    {
        if(cases[i].[j] == seen[w]); //here
        else
            seen.push_back(cases[i].[j]); //here
    }
}
```

The error is that there is a dot between `[i]` and `[j]`, which is causing th error. Just remove it.

The other problem that you have is that vector indexes start with 0, not 1, and they end at size, so the number has to be less than, not less than equal to size, and the index should start at 0.

Comment: it compile, and i got a runtime error removing the "." implies that cases is a 2d array.@Arnav Borborah

Comment: Is it not a 2d array? Cases is a 2d array, or vector to be more specific. If you check your code, you declared it as: `vector<vector<int>> cases;
`

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do indexing access like this:

```
            if(cases[i].[j] == seen[w]);
            else
                seen.push_back(cases[i].[j]);
```

Replace this with:

```
            if(cases[i][j] == seen[w]);
            else
                seen.push_back(cases[i][j]);
```

Note the removed dots.

Why are you doing such an unconventional `if` structure? I'd write this as

```
            if(cases[i][j] != seen[w])
                seen.push_back(cases[i][j]);
```

SIDE NOTES: As other people have pointed out (and I have noticed myself :) ), there are many other errors and mishaps within your code as it stands:

- You are trying to use 1-based indexing. C uses 0-based indexing, so your loops over array-like objects should go from 0 until `< array_length`
- `cin >> M[j];` is invalid, as the `vector` is empty. Read an `int` and `.push` in into the vector
- You should empty the `M` vector in each iteration of the reading loop, otherwise it will still contain values from the previous iteration (I'm sure that's not what you want)

Comment: i did remove "." . at runtime i got " exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) ". cases is not 2d array but a vector object that holds arrays of vectors of type int.@InternetAussie